# Load Images from Phone storage to GridView using Picasso

Tags: android, gridview, picasso

I have downloaded the images in a folder on my phone and I also have the path to those images. How can I load all the images from that folder in a gridView using Picasso library?

UPDATE:

```
GridView gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +"/Gallery/Mix/");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

Now what is the next step, how can I load all the files from **Mix** folder to gridView?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some code and what problem you are having.

Comment: Plz check that, I am very new so I dont know what to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html). It walks you through adding ImageViews to a GridView.

Then instead of using `mThumbIds` as your list of resource ids you can use `File[] filesArray = new file.listFiles();` as your list of image files and loop through it instead.

Then replace the line `imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);` in `ImageAdapter` with `Picasso.with(context).load(filesArray[position]).into(imageView);` to use Picasso (got from [here](http://square.github.io/picasso/)).

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. I have one little confusion. You mean I should remove private Integer[] mThumbIds = {...}; and use these lines instead File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +"/Gallery/Mix/");     File[] filesArray = new file.listFiles();     right???

Comment: yeah, kind of... I made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Roarster31/8c80907dd2c6ac077cd5) here you can use that explains it a bit better